# get cursor from MQL query, Freebase

Tags: freebase, mql

I am trying to get the 'cursor' value returned in a MQL query by following [this example](http://www.freebase.com/docs/mql/ch04.html#envelopeparameters). Though [my attempt](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?cursor=true&query=%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/music/album%22,%22artist%22%3a%22The%20Police%22,%22name%22%3anull,%22limit%22:10%7D%5D) produces the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "cursor is invalid.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "parameters.cursor"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "cursor is invalid."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new API, the starting value for the `cursor` parameter is null, not the value `true` like before.  Try [this](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?cursor=&query=%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/music/album%22,%22artist%22%3a%22The%20Police%22,%22name%22%3anull,%22limit%22:10%7D%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Docs here
http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_Read_Service